# Extend the lifetime of a temporary variable outside its block

Tags: rust

In Rust I sometimes find myself wanting to write code like this:

```rust
fn read_possibly_compressed_data(
    mut reader: impl Read,
) -> Result<()> {
    let is_compressed = reader.read_u8()? == 1;

    let reader: &mut dyn Read = if is_compressed {
        &mut ZlibDecoder::new(reader)
    } else {
        &mut reader
    };

    ...
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work for obvious reasons - the lifetime of `ZlibDecoder::new()` only extends to the end of its block so I can't return a reference to it.

The obvious solution is to put it outside the block, but then you have to do some initialisation, or maybe put it in an `Option<>`:

```
fn read_possibly_compressed_data(
    mut reader: impl Read,
) -> Result<()> {
    let is_compressed = reader.read_u8()? == 1;

    let mut zlib_decoder = ZlibDecoder::new(Cursor::default());

    let reader: &mut dyn Read = if is_compressed {
        zlib_decoder = ZlibDecoder::new(reader);
        &mut zlib_decoder
    } else {
        &mut reader
    };

    ...
```

This is slightly less optimal than if the first code just worked. Is there a better way that I'm missing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer while writing this, guided by Rust's excellent error messages. You can just declare the variable outside the block and assuming the flow control is right you don't have to initialise it:

```rust
fn read_possibly_compressed_data(
    mut reader: impl Read,
) -> Result<()> {
    let is_compressed = reader.read_u8()? == 1;

    let mut zlib_decoder;

    let reader: &mut dyn Read = if is_compressed {
        zlib_decoder = ZlibDecoder::new(reader);
        &mut zlib_decoder
    } else {
        &mut reader
    };

    ...
```

Comment: Consider returning a tuple from your `if` so you can do `let (reader, decoder) = if ...` where `decoder` becomes `Option<ZlibDecoder>`.

Comment: I don't really follow you. I don't want two readers. I just one one - either the original one or the `ZlibDecoder`.

Comment: You could declare it as a `Box<dyn Read>` that picks up one of the two things.

Comment: Could do but there's no need here, and it's an extra heap allocation.